# Convergence of $\int _0^{\infty }\:\left(-1\right)^{\left[x^2\right]}$ It's clear to me it doesn't converge absolutely as $\int_0^\infty\:1$ doesn't

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

I have to find out if $\int _0^{\infty }\:\left(-1\right)^{\left[x^2\right]}$ converges / diverges / converges absolutely.

It's clear to me it doesn't converge absolutely because $\int _0^{\infty}\:1$ doesn't converge, but I don't know how to go on from here.

Comment: Find the value of the integral from 0 to root n.

Comment: How? does the integrand has indefinite integral?

Comment: It is a step function. For example, on [0, 1) it is just 1. So the integral is 1.

Comment: I don't understand how it helps me if I'm looking for the limit at infinity

Comment: The integral to infinity is the sum of the integrals from 0 to 1, from 1 to root 2, from root 2 to root 3, ....

Answer (score 4):

The integral from $\sqrt n$ to $\sqrt{n+1}$ is
$$(-1)^n\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n\right).$$
The improper integral is therefore the sum of an alternating series. The absolute values of the terms are monotonically decreasing to zero  and therefore the series is convergent.

Therefore the integral converges.